# How to fix 'element implicitly has an 'any' type. TS7031' for function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to react am getting the error

> Binding element 'onClick' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031

On the following code

```
const CloseButton = ({ onClick }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <CloseIcon className={classes.closeButtonStyles} onClick={onClick} />;
};
```

I know I need to define a type but I don't know which for an onClick function. Google is not giving me any help.

Would anyone know what type I am meant to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what `CloseIcon`'s `onClick` prop expects. Many native HTML elements will accept a React `MouseEventHandler` for `onClick`.

For example:

```
import React, { MouseEventHandler } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ onClick }: { onClick: MouseEventHandler }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>Button</button>
  );
}
```

So you can try:

```
import { MouseEventHandler } from 'react';


const CloseButton = ({ onClick }: { onClick: MouseEventHandler }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <CloseIcon className={classes.closeButtonStyles} onClick={onClick} />;
};
```

Comment: Is there some way to remove the redundancy here of saying `onClick` twice? It's no big deal maybe with just one argument, but with multiple arguments it gets painful

Comment: `const CloseButton = (props: { onClick: MouseEventHandler }) =>`